# Get the ID of the latest post

Tags: custom-post-types, posts, query-posts, query, get-posts

Been all over looking for the best way to do this.

I want to get the ID of the latest post of a certain post_type.

How can I do this in the cheapest way possible (by cheapest I mean using the least queries, and no loops or post rewinding)?

Surely there is a quick method?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

```
$latest_cpt = get_posts("post_type=yourcpt&numberposts=1");
echo $latest_cpt[0]->ID
```

The only cheaper way than above, I can think of, would be to write your own SQL query to just return the one post and only the column ID.

Comment: Yes, that's it! I've been skirting around it. Thanks @brady

Comment: `get_posts("post_type=yourcpt&numberposts=1&fields=ids") ` to only return the post id, nothing else, a little bit faster this way:)

Comment: `post_type=post` to get default posts.

Comment: Using @passatgt 's method, the echo statement would be `echo $latest_cpt[0];`, there's no getting the ->ID from an object.

Answer (score 3):

A more pure SQL way:

```
function GetLastPostId()
{
    global $wpdb;

    $query = "SELECT ID FROM $wpdb->posts ORDER BY ID DESC LIMIT 0,1";

    $result = $wpdb->get_results($query);
    $row = $result[0];
    $id = $row->ID;

    return $id;
}
```